# Filter array based on dynamic array parameter Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Good evening everyone, I’m new to vuejs.
I have this code:

```
mounted () {
EventBus.$on(‘FreshDeleteData’, (response) => {
const filtersList = this.jsondata.filter(element => element !== response[0])
this.jsondata=filtersList
})
}
```

I want array ‘response’ be dynamically on comparison because i have many object to compare

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: If you want to filter out all elements that are in response then: `this.jsondata.filter(element => !response.includes(element))`.

Comment: Thank you, you save my time